# Haskell Extract the Length from an IO (Either Reply [Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString])

Tags: haskell, redis

Need to Patch a Haskell project from a developer that has left, but I'm a complete Haskell Noob.

Trying to write a function that will return the COUNT of all Redis keys matching a pattern.  Interactively, it looks like this:

```
*MyProj S R U>let res = runRedis conn $ keys "MP:Users*"
*MyProj S R U> res
Right ["MP:Users:00:13:95:12:7D:85","MP:Users:00:13:95:12:7D:84","MP:Users:APP"]
*MyProj S R U> :t res
res :: IO (Either Reply [Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString])
```

So in this case I simply want the length of the Right ByteString array response from Redis.  *3* in this case.  Any problems or no response and this function can just return 0.

I really don't have a clue how to do this in Haskell,  The closest thing I can think of is this:

```
redisKeyCount :: Connection -> BSC.ByteString -> IO Int
redisKeyCount conn keypattern =
  runRedis conn $ do
    response <- keys keypattern
    case response of
      [BSC.ByteString] allkeys ->
        case length allkeys of
          Just (n, _) -> return n
          _           -> return 0
      _ -> return 0
```

But, of course that does not work.  I've tried dozens of variations of the above.  How to extract and return **just the length** of the Right-hand side of this res :: IO (Either Reply [Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString]) ?

Comment: `len <- fmap (fmap length) res`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close! The key is to make your pattern match for `response` match its type. Since `keys keypattern :: IO (Either Reply [ByteString])`, `response` has the type `Either Reply [ByteString]`.

`Either a b` has two constructors - `Left :: a -> Either a b` and `Right :: b -> Either a b`, and these are the patterns we can match when we use `case` to deconstruct an `Either a b` value.

```
redisKeyCount :: Connection -> BSC.ByteString -> IO Int
redisKeyCount conn keypattern =
  runRedis conn $ do
    response <- keys keypattern
    return $ case response of
      Left _reply -> 0
      Right allKeys -> length allKeys
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  When I try that, I get an error on the Right line:library/Redis.hs:66:24:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Redis Int’ with actual type ‘Int’
    In the expression: length allKeys
    In a case alternative: Right allKeys -> length allKeys

Comment: Dave Collins: d'oh. That's what I get for answering w/o compiling. Fixed (hopefully)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm Cargo-culting the Haskell in a big way now!

Answer (score 2):

A little elaboration starting from @rampion's answer:

```
redisKeyCount :: Connection -> BSC.ByteString -> IO Int
redisKeyCount conn keypattern =
  runRedis conn $ do
    response <- keys keypattern
    return $ case response of
      Left _reply -> 0
      Right allKeys -> length allKeys
```

The last `case` can be shortened using the `either` eliminator:

```
redisKeyCount :: Connection -> BSC.ByteString -> IO Int
redisKeyCount conn keypattern =
  runRedis conn $ do
    response <- keys keypattern
    return $ either (const 0) length response
```

Then, the `x <- ... ; return $ f x` pattern is `fmap` (AKA `<$>`):

```
redisKeyCount :: Connection -> BSC.ByteString -> IO Int
redisKeyCount conn keypattern =
  runRedis conn (either (const 0) length <$> keys keypattern)
```